# actions.MoveToElement() not working on ie 11

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

The same method used in the test automation project I wrote in c # does not work in internet explorer 11 even though the movement method I use is chrome, firefox and edge. It does not give any errors, but the next action is fail

```
log.Debug("fare " + by + " üzeriine dogru haraket ediyor, webelement label ");
IWebElement element = GetElement(by);
Actions Actions = new Actions(Driver);
WaitElementToClickable(Driver, by, 5);
Actions.MoveToElement(element);
Actions.Perform();
WaitElementToClickable(Driver, by, 5);
```

Comment: _Selenium_ and _IEDriverServer_ versions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a long time trying to get actions to work across all browsers, and for IE I found the following helped.

Selenium webdriver v2.29.0 (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) added:

```
IEDriver supports "requireWindowFocus" desired capability. When
using this and native events, the IE driver will demand focus and
user interactions will use SendInput() for simulating user
interactions. Note that this will mean you MUST NOT use the
machine running IE for anything else as the tests are running.
```

When I set the IEDriver I use:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.requireWindowFocus();
webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

And all my move to and click events work fine. I'm using IE11.125-11.309 and Selenium (java bindings) 3.7.1.

Comment: yes thats working

in c#InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
ieOptions.RequireWindowFocus = true;